# Can I create library (dll) project on ironruby?

Tags: dll, ironruby

Can I create library (dll) project on ironruby ? and How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to creating a .NET assembly which you can use from other .NET apps. For that you can use the IronRubyEmbeddedApps project, which can be found here - https://github.com/rifraf/IronRubyEmbeddedApps